# How to install openCV2 for python in ManjaroLinux?

Tags: opencv, manjaro

I tried several websites but haven't found anything useful. I have installed numpy using

```
pacman -S python2-numpy
```

It seems to be installed.

But I want to install openCV2 in ManjaroLinux. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

It post is from 7 months ago but I think the answer is:
    `sudo pip install opencv-python`